# JavaScript ternary if statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, shortcut, conditional-operator

I would like to know what's the shortcode of if in javascript?

Like in php:

```
$res = ($x > $y)? $x: $y;
```

What's its conversion in javascript?

Comment: -1 not searching even at least once http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+ternary+operator

Comment: hm... didn't notice... its the same... thnx all

Comment: You don't need to change anything: the above PHP code is already a valid JavaScript. `$res = ($x > $y)? $x: $y;` (you can use $ in variable names)

Comment: This happens when you don't know the name of the construct, he is calling it `shortcut if`, if you search for that, you'd find none of the dups. I'm reseting one of the down votes.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's the same in javascript :)

```
var res = (x > y) ? x : y;
```

Answer (score 5):

```
var x = 2;
var y = 3;
var res = (x > y)? x: y;
```

Although perhaps the following would be better:

```
var res = Math.max(x, y);
```

Answer (score 3):

It is the same in javascript:

`res = (y < x) ? x : y;` or `res = (x > y) ? x : y;`

Answer (score 3):

The same. It is called ternary:

```
var x = 10, y = 50, res = 0; 
res = (x > y) ? x : y; 
alert(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are: `var res = x>y?x:y;`